# Using GLYPHICONS's free pngs with classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, glyphicons

[Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/) allows free use of its halflings icon set via [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-glyphs):  Bootstrap comes with two files (a .woff and a .svg) that are loaded as font files by the browser.  Glyphicons also allows you to download PNGs of all the rest of its icons.

Is there a way to use bootstrap-esque classes in order to load the PNGs, or do I have to use ye old `<img />` tags?

Comment: If you're using the free version you'd have to use `img` tags or CSS

Comment: I'm fine with writing some CSS... I just don't know what that CSS would look like

Comment: `background-image: url(image.png);`

Comment: Nope, just hadn't marked the answer yet.

Comment: You actually can do it smarter - http://jsfiddle.net/0hrs0wf1/ (no width height is required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
.glyphicon-envelope:before {
   content: "";
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-image: url(envelope.png);
   display: block;
}
```

The width and height would need to be adjusted to fit the image size correctly